# How to transform and store sql results in php array/object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an SQL data that looks like this

```
|username|FinalState|Duration       |
|user1   |Status1   |00:02:13.747   |
|user1   |Status2   |00:00:20.027   |
|user1   |Status3   |00:00:10.818   |
|user1   |Status4   |00:00:00.000   |
|user2   |Status1   |00:49:59.945   |
|user2   |Status2   |00:18:18.248   |
|user2   |Status5   |00:00:00.450   |
```

I need to transform it into an PHP array / object such that it should look like this

```
$data["user1"] = [status1 => 00:02:13.747 , status2 => 00:00:20.027 .... ]
$data["user2"] = [status1 => 00:49:59.945 , status2 => 00:18:18.248 .... ]
```

The problem is that `FinalState` is a  different combination for users.

Comment: What have you tried? My generic advice would be to iterate and build the array yourself.

Comment: The last time I did something similar was to iterate through all the values. But in this case the status column is subject to change while in my previous attempt the status was fixed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume you retrieve all the data so now you have an array as:

```
$arr = array(["username" => "user1", "FinalState" => "Status1", "Duration" => "00:02:13.747"], ["username" => "user1", "FinalState" => "Status2", "Duration" => "00:00:20.027"], ...);
```

You can get this data by using simple select on all - and use FETCH_DATA_ASSOC flag.

Now, all you need is simple `foreach` loop as:

```
foreach($arr as $e) {
    $data[$e["username"]][$e["FinalState"]] = $e["Duration"];
}
```

And that it - Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/dmhBY)

Comment: Awesome. This worked. The last time I did similar was to iterate through every array and it was not the best method.
Thank you.